# A particle is moving along the curve $y= 2 \sqrt{2 x + 2}$

Tags: calculus

A particle is moving along the curve $y= 2 \sqrt{2 x + 2}$. As the particle passes through the point  $(1, 4)$, its x-coordinate increases at a rate of $2$ units per second. Find the rate of change of the distance from the particle to the origin at this instant.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any thoughts and can share what you have tried? Regards

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: The distance from the origin is given in general by $$D=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{x^2+4(2x+2)}=\sqrt{x^2+8x+4}.$$ You're trying to find $\frac{dD}{dt}$ when $x=1,$ given that $\frac{dx}{dt}=2$ units per second when $x=1$. Any ideas how you might do that?

Comment: the next step could be

2DdDdt=4+2ydydt

Comment: I think you are trying to say $$2D\frac{dD}{dt}=4+2y\frac{dy}{dt},$$ but I'm not sure why you're doing this, as we don't know anything about the rate of change of $y$, nor have we written $D$ in terms of $y$. Incidentally, if you want to see how something is formatted, just right-click on it, go to "Show Math As," then click "TeX Commands," and a window will pop up to show you how it was done. Put the result between `$ $`, and you'll get the same result. For example, `$\frac{dD}{dt}$` gives you $\frac{dD}{dt}$.

Comment: im really bad at diffentiation

Comment: we  i got the value of $\frac{dy}{dt}$=2 
now i have the value of $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$

Comment: so how would i find the value of $\frac{dD}{dt}$

Comment: **Hint**: By chain rule, $$\frac{dD}{dt}=\frac{dD}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}.$$

Comment: $\frac{dD}{dt}$= $\frac{(y-4)(x-1)}{d2sqrt(y-4)^2+(x-1)^2}$

Comment: I'm not sure how you got that. Take another look at $$D=\sqrt{x^2+8x+4}.$$ What is $\frac{dD}{dx}$?

Comment: $\frac{dD}{dx}$=$\frac{2x+8}{2sqrtx^2+8x+4}$

Comment: Yes. That tells us that $$\frac{dD}{dt}=\frac{dD}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}= \frac{2x+8}{2\sqrt{x^2+8x+4}}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}.$$ Now, substitute the values that we were given for $x$ and $\frac{dx}{dt}.$ Don't forget the units!